# Checar se diretório 'B' está dentro de diretório 'A'

Tags: python, python-3.x, diretório

Estou desenvolvendo um script que checa a última data de acesso de cada arquivo dentro de toda árvore de um diretório escolhido. Os arquivos com mais de X dias sem acesso serão movidos para um outro diretório.
Por precaução, preciso que seja detectado se o diretório de destino está dentro do diretório de origem. Caso esteja, o script solicitará um outro diretório de destino que não dentro do diretório de origem.

Esta é a parte em que é solicitado o diretório de destino:

```
msg_error = '[ERRO] Diretorio invalido, tente novamente:\n'
pasta_destino = str(input('Insira o diretorio de destino\n'))
while not path.isdir(pasta_destino):
    pasta_destino = str(input(msg_error))
```

Estou muito tempo tentando checar isso e tentei de tudo. Estou aprendendo python a apenas uma semana e algo mais próximo da checagem que consegui montar foi isso:

```
if path.exists(pasta_destino in pasta_origem):
     print('Escolha outro diretório que não dentro do diretório de origem.\n')
```

Infelizmente não funciona, retorna 'True' independente dos caminhos inseridos.

Tenho certeza que esta é uma checagem simples, conseguem me ajudar? Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

**Use Pathlib:**

```
from pathlib import Path
def is_sub(root, directory):
    p = Path(root)
    return True if list(p.glob(directory)) else False
```

**Teste no Linux (terminal ipython)**

```
mkdir ~/teste1
cd ~/teste1
mkdir dir1

is_sub('.','dir1')
True

is_sub('.','dir2')
False

is_sub('/home/sidon','Downloads')
True
```

**Teste no WIndows:**

```
is_sub('/','users')
True
```

Comment: Só funciona se o diretório estiver imediatamente dentro do outro, ou seja, não consegue detectar o caso do `directory` a verificar estar a 2 ou mais níveis de subdiretórios dentro do diretório raiz `root`.

Comment: @nosklo, foquei na pergunta, e não percebi essa necessidade, mas seria bem simples adaptar para o que vc sugere.

Answer (score 1):

```
def subdir(pai, filho):
    return os.path.abspath(filho).startswith(os.path.abspath(pai) + os.path.sep)
```

Note que essa função não verifica se os diretórios **existem**, somente se um está contido no outro, porém, seria fácil modificar e acrescentar mais essa verificação.

Comment: Cara, a ideia é boa mas tem que tratar um negócio, o `abspath` retorna um path sem a barra no final. Se você for usar comparação de strings pra isso tem que adicionar essa barra, senão seu código vai dizer que `/minha/pasta_filha/teste` está contida em `/minha/pasta`

Comment: @fernandosavio bem pensado, editei a resposta